# Getting specific elements in a vector

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, stdvector

I'm trying to get a specific element inside of a vector.
For example,

Lets say I have a vector.

```
std::vector<Tile> TileList;
```

The Vector is of size MAP_HEIGHT = 30, MAP_WIDTH = 200
So its total size is MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_WIDTH = 6000.
I use a double nested for loop to iterate through and create a vector full of tiles.

```
for(int Y = 0; Y < MAP_HEIGHT; Y++)
{
   for(int X = 0; X < MAP_WIDTH; X++)
   {
        Tile TempTile;

        fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d ", &TempTile.TileID, &TempTile.TypeID);

        TileList.push_back(TempTile);

   }

}
```

Now my questions is lets say I iterate through

```
int ID = 0;

for(int Y = 0; Y < MAP_HEIGHT; Y++)
{
   for(int X = 0; X < MAP_WIDTH; X++)
   {
        TileList[ID].do stuff with it

        //Check for the tile above this tile
        // Find a way to calculate the ID of the tile above this tile
        int IDoftilabove = ID - do something;
        if(TileList[IDoftilabove].variable == TILE_SOMETHING)
        {
           do stuff
        }
       ID++;
    }
```

How do I calculate the ID of an element above(well technically before this ID) inside the vector based on the current element I'm on.

Illustration:
say i have a matrix 5x5, 
Lets say my current ID is 8. so I am on the second row number 3.

```
1  2 *3* 4  5
1  2 (3) 4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
```

Now I want the ID of the element in vector that is directly above me which is the ID 3, first row number 3. and this is just assuming the the MAP_WIDTH = 5 and the MAP_HEIGHT = 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8 - 5 = 3`

Current - `MAP_WIDTH` = Above

Comment: I feel dumb... thanks! I was over thinking this. I should have done the illustration for myself to answer this question ><

Comment: No problem, we all do sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily determine the `(row,col)` coordinates given the `ID`:

```
row = ID / MAP_WIDTH;
col = ID % MAP_WIDTH;
```

If you want to know what is the coordinate from the element above:

```
row--;
ID_above = row * MAP_WIDTH + col;
```

The same applies if you want to know what is the element below:

```
row++;
ID_below = row * MAP_WIDTH + col;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to map between linear and 2d indices. This is pretty straightforward.

```
   int rect2lin(int w, int x, int y) { return y*w+x; }
   void lin2rect(int w, int i, int * x, int * y) { *y = i/w; *x = i%w; }
```

So in your example, the ID of the element above (X,Y) would be rect2lin(MAP_WIDTH, X,Y-1), which is simply (Y-1)*MAP_WIDTH+X. This generalizes straightforwardly to higher numbers of dimension. For example, i=(z*h+y)*w+x for 3d, and so on.